# Linear regression by group using loops

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a dataset which contain a lot of variable and I need to do linear regression by countries. I have 7 countries here.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUxB8.png)

Now, I want to use a loop to do regression separately.
Here is my code:

[image]

```
lmcountry(witd_hw$countryest,witd_hw$AverageIncome,witd_hw$sqincome)
```

While, there seems to have a mistake:
     object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

but actually I can do the regression like:

```
lm(witd_hw$countryest~witd_hw$AverageIncome+witd_hw$sqincome,data=witd_hw[witd_hw$Country=="China",])
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code, just copy the code and paste as text. Further, please make this question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by adding the output of `dput(head(with_hw))` (or another small representative chunk of data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with a for loop but with the list apply function. First split the dataframe into sub-frames by country. Then apply `lm` to each of the subsets:

```
# Reproducible data example
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), country = sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 100, replace=TRUE))

list_of_country_dfs = split(df, df$country)

results = lapply(list_of_country_dfs, function(dat) lm(y ~ x, data = dat))
lapply(results, summary)
```

Comment: @VeraCai could you accept the answer if it works for you? Thanks